# Advance Linear Algebra Textbook Recommendations

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, advice

Does anyone know of a good textbook that covers the following topics: linear regression, ridge regression, lasso regression, principal component analysis, multi dimensional scaling, perceptron, support vector machine, spines, kernel methods, and concentration of measure.

I am a first year graduate student and with classes all online, I'm struggling to understand all of the concepts from the online lectures alone. Also, the course does not have a textbook, otherwise I would begin by turning to the textbook to better my understanding.

Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that these topics are not the domain of what is usually referred to as "advanced linear algebra".  Instead, these are usually considered to be a part of "numerical linear algebra", "numerical analysis", "numerical optimization", or "machine learning".

Comment: Your professor should have suggestions for supplemental reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is a textbook on **Statistical Learning** or **Machine Learning**.

An excellent book is [An Introduction to Statistical Learning (ISLR)](http://faculty.marshall.usc.edu/gareth-james/ISL/) (which is by far the best book for beginners).

After finishing ISLR you can consider either [Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning (PRML)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2006/01/Bishop-Pattern-Recognition-and-Machine-Learning-2006.pdf) or [The Elements of Statistical Learning (ESL)](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ehastie/ElemStatLearn/) for a more comprehensive coverage.

All the 3 books are freely available for download.

Answer (score 1):

Introduction to Computational Linear Algebra by Nabil Nassif is a fantastic book